# Is there any way to create a captions system in Unity 2018.1?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, captions

is there any way to create a closed captions/subtitles system? (I'm not voice acting the game,I just want subtitles.)
I'm using Unity 2018 and I'm new to C#

Comment: Do you need something like that (from Unity's asset store)? https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/easy-subtitles-and-closed-captions-system-12168

Comment: You may also want to ask this question here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/